# unable to check file with extensions

Tags: powershell

```
$ext = "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\project1\my scripts\extension.txt"
$a = Get-Content $ext
$a

$list = dir C:\Users\SyedNasiruddinS\Desktop\* -include $a |  Select 
Directory,Fullname,Name,Length,CreationTime 
$list | Export-Csv "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\results.csv"
```

extension.txt file contains list of file extentions like *.txt, *.xlsx $a is not fetching the extensions (content of $a) and output file is blank.

When i do with this data is coming but i want to keep extensions on text file

```
$list = dir C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\* -include *.txt, *.xlsx, *.exe |   Select Directory,Fullname,Name,Length,CreationTime 
$list | Export-Csv "C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\results.csv"
```

Comment: You might want to start accepting some answers...

Comment: Get-Content does what it says on the tin. Do a `Test-Path $ext` and then `notepad $ext` to ensure it exists and has contents.

Comment: So, your `$a` is blank? Start debugging from there, check if `Get-Content` throws an access denied error for example.

Comment: the following i get when i run on Get-Content

PS C:\windows\system32> $ext = "C:\Users\SyedNasiruddinS\Desktop\project1\my scripts\extension.txt"
$a = Get-Content $ext
$a
output:
*.txt, *.xlsx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment where you advised that `$a` contains a comma separated list of extensions, you may need to do this:

```
$ext = "extension.txt"
$a = ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($ext)) -split ','
$a

$list = dir * -include $a |  Select Directory,Fullname,Name,Length,CreationTime 
$list
```

**Explanation:**

The `-split ','` splits the single string in to an array of strings, which the -Include property then accepts/processes as multiple input.

Alternatively, change your extension.txt file so that each extension is on a new line (and remove the , characters).

Comment: extension.txt contents *.txt, *.xlsx, *.exe
what i want basically is to get these "*.txt, *.xlsx, *.exe" after include in the code the time of compling and execute

Comment: So then my answer should work for you. Please accept it if it does.

Comment: My answer will work for you because `-Include` accepts array input and using `-split` results in an array object.

Comment: also getting this error
Get-Content : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'split'.
At line:2 char:23
+ $a = Get-Content $ext -split ','

Comment: And @SyedNasir You need to use your head instead of cargo copypasting.